# Is it a calendula?

Tags: identification

I had planted some seeds of Calendula in my garden. This plant came out at that spot, which I think looks like calendula.
[image]

This is the stem portion.
[image]

However no flower is blooming, instead the tip of the plant is becoming like this:
[image]

with cotton or something like that
[image]

Is it a weed, not a calendula?

Comment: Is the plant sticky to the touch?

Comment: No, it is not sticky, rather feels like velvet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calendula leaves are broader and the flowers quite different. Your plant is possibly *Valerianella* species, otherwise known as Corn Salad or Mache. Cultivated varieties generally have smooth leaves, this one has hairy leaves. There is a species *V. eriocarpa* which is hairy and has the dense, tiny flowers in your photo. Found in the south of the UK, native to the Mediterranean.